# How to migrate a list from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-server, migration

I must migrate a lot of list from `SharePoint 2010`, to `SharePoint 2013`. Sometimes this List have got more then `50 MB` data.

How could I migrate them with Content? How to migrate with person who made the element list and with date of make this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways to migrate a list from sharepiont 2010 to 2013.

**Using Import & Export method**

- export the list in sharepoint 2010
- Open the Cab file and change the version number from 14 to 15
- Import in Sharepoint 2013.
  Check the complete process [over here](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html)

**Using the 3rd Party Tool**

- use 3rd party tool to move the list between the envrinoment, this will help to save the metadata.

**Using the Database method**

- You can use the database migrate approach to get this done.

Comment: I find this article too Yesterday :)